# Filter emails on command with Yahoo! Mail?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I know you can set filters for certain emails by right-clicking on them, clicking "filter emails like this", and filling out the form. But, that does nothing to existing emails. Is there a way for me to run these filters to move emails that already exist?

Comment: If for incoming mails here check this http://help.yahoo.com/qe/uk/tutorials/mmail/mm_filter1.html.